# How to insert data under secure rest endpoints by spring security using MYSQL

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring boot 2. For creating rest-full service using spring security and MySQL based authentication, I am following this [article](https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/spring-boot-spring-mvc-spring-security-mysql-a5d8545d837d) but got stucked in registration process.

**Problem 1**: I am unable to understand URL requesting pattern to register a user with particular role.
**Problem 2:** On browser side, If I hit `localhost:8080` then I get login page which I haven't implemented. Why I am getting a UI and from where?

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>badar.tme</groupId>
    <artifactId>tme</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>tme</name>
    <description>TME ordering system developed by ONSETS</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <!-- spring security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[Here is Login UI which is miracle for me right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUNpz.png)

Auth Controller (rest controller)

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public ResponseEntity<Users> createNewUser(@Valid Users user, String role) {

            Users userExists = userService.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail());
            if (userExists == null) {
                ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
            } 
            return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.save(user, role));
        }
```

WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter child file

```
package com.tme.runner;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

import com.tme.service.MyUserDetailsService;

@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = com.tme.repo.UserRepository.class)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Autowired
    private MyUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

//    @Bean
//    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
//        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
//    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
                auth
                    .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }




    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/v1/**").hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .formLogin().disable();

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static/**", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**");
    }

}
```

User Entity class

```
package com.tme.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Email;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;
import java.util.Set;


/**
 * @author badar
 */
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class Users {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private int id;
    @Column(name = "user_name")
    @Length(min = 5, message = "*Your user name must have at least 5 characters")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide a user name")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "email")
    @Email(message = "*Please provide a valid Email")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide an email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password")
    @Length(min = 5, message = "*Your password must have at least 5 characters")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your last name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "active")
    private Boolean active;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Roles> roles;

    public Users() {}
    public Users(
            String userName,
            String email,
            String password,
            String name,
            String lastName, 
            Boolean active) {

        this.userName = userName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.active = active;
    }
    public Users(
            String userName,
            String email,
            String password,
            String name,
            String lastName, 
            Boolean active, 
            Set<Roles> roles) {

        this.userName = userName;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.active = active;
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Boolean getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(Boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Set<Roles> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Roles> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }



}
```

Service Class

```
package com.tme.service;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.tme.model.Roles;
import com.tme.model.Users;
import com.tme.repo.RoleRepository;
import com.tme.repo.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UsersServices {

    @Autowired(required=false)
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    @Autowired(required=false)
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @Autowired(required=false)
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

//    public UsersServices(BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder,UserRepository userRepository,
//                       RoleRepository roleRepository
//                       ) {
//        this.userRepository = userRepository;
//        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
//        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
//    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    public List<Users> findAll(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Users findUserByEmail(String email) {
        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    public Users findUserByUserName(String userName) {
        return userRepository.findByUserName(userName);
    }

    public Optional<Users> findById(Long id){
        return userRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public Users save(Users data) {
        data.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(data.getPassword()));
        data.setActive(true);
        Roles userRole = roleRepository.findByRole("ADMIN");
        data.setRoles(new HashSet<Roles>(Arrays.asList(userRole)));
        return userRepository.save(data);
    }

    public Users save(Users data, String role) {
        data.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(data.getPassword()));
        Roles userRole = roleRepository.findByRole(role);
        data.setRoles(new HashSet<Roles>(Arrays.asList(userRole)));
        return userRepository.save(data);
    }

    public void deleteById(Long id) {
        userRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

MyUserDetailsService class

```
@Service
public class MyUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    private UsersServices userService;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        Users user = userService.findUserByEmail(email);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Not found!");
        }

        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getUserAuthority(user.getRoles());
        return buildUserForAuthentication(user, authorities);
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getUserAuthority(Set<Roles> userRoles) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> roles = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (Roles role : userRoles) {
            roles.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getRole()));
        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>(roles);
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }

    private UserDetails buildUserForAuthentication(Users user, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(),
                user.getActive(), true, true, true, authorities);
    }
}
```

MyUserDetail

```
public class MyUserDetails extends Users implements UserDetails{

    private String userName;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private String lastName; 
    private Boolean active;


    public MyUserDetails(Users user) {
        this.userName = user.getUserName();
        this.email = user.getEmail();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.name = user.getName();
        this.lastName = user.getLastName();
        this.active = user.getActive();
    }



    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return getRoles()
                .stream()
                .map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getRole()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return active;
    }

}
```

I think I have done every thing. Don't know how to save/Regsiter New user. If I will be able to regsiter a user then can test my login URL. Thanks inadvance.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line in your `application.properties` file

```
management.security.enabled= false
```